# What is qw in Perl?

Tags: perl

What does `qw` stand for? Is there any documentation where I can read about it?

Also, how is it related to array declaration? For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@days = qw/Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun/;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *I always wonder what is qw stands for!*

It stands for "quote words" (or something similar), as it is a quoting construct like single quotes (`q/.../` aka `'...'`) and double quotes (`qq/.../` aka `"..."`), but it returns a list of words.

---

> *any related document to read on qw ?*

The [`qw`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qw%2f_STRING_%2f) operator is documeted in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

```
qw/Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun/
```

is equivalent to

```
split ' ', q/Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun/
```

---

> *how is it related array declaration?*

It has no relation to array declaration. Arrays are both declared and defined using `my @array` (and rarely `our @array`).